# How do I get Java to implement exponentially larger numbers in a while loop without running out of memory?

Tags: java, debugging

Okay so this is my first program ever written after Hello World, currently learning on Udemy. The goal of the program is to have some input value, and then that number get squared. A Loop runs as long as the input value is greater than 12% of it's squared value. So if it is greater, it squares the input value then reruns the loop until the input is <= 12% of it's squared value.

Two questions: Why didn't my code stop at 16? 16 is less than 12% of 256. So my code is definitely buggy somewhere, but I'm not able to identify it.

Also, as you can see below, the code kept running until it hit 0, which I assumed is because the continually squared data exceeded their desired storage. Is there a way to get around this so I can have a longer run time for other projects?

Below is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define the variables
        long inputValue = 2;
        long iValuesquared = (long) Math.pow(inputValue, 2);

        // conditional statement checking if input is less than 12% of squared value.
        if (inputValue > (0.12 * iValuesquared)) {
            System.out.println(inputValue + " is greater than 12% of it's squared value.");

            while (inputValue > (0.12 * iValuesquared)) {
                System.out.println(inputValue + " is greater than 12% of it's squared value.");
                inputValue *= inputValue;
                System.out.println(inputValue);

                if (inputValue <= (0.12 * iValuesquared)) {
                    System.out.println(inputValue + " is LESS than 12% of it's squared value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
2 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
4
4 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
16
16 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
256
256 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
65536
65536 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
4294967296
4294967296 is greater than 12% of it's squared value.
0
0 is LESS than 12% of it's squared value

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: use `BigInteger`. that might solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The while loop has a test involving iValuesquared, but it does not get updated. Thus, the condition is always met as inputValue grows.

```
while (inputValue > (0.12*iValuesquared)) {
 System.out.println(inputValue +" is greater than 12% of it's squared value.");
 inputValue*=iValuesquared;
 iValuesquared = (long) Math.pow(inputValue, 2); // inputValue * inputValue works, too
 System.out.println(inputValue);
}
```

You can also simplify the program as the first `if` is redundant with the while loop:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //define the variables
    long inputValue = 2;
    long iValuesquared = inputValue * inputValue;

    //conditional statement checking if input is less than 12% of squared value.
    while (inputValue > (0.12*iValuesquared)) {
      System.out.println(inputValue +" is greater than 12% of it's squared value.");
      inputValue = iValuesquared; // saves computing it twice
      iValuesquared = inputValue * inputValue;
      System.out.println(inputValue);
    }

    System.out.println(inputValue + " is LESS than 12% of it's squared value");
  }
}
```

Comment: Question: Why do we have to redefine iValuesquared = inputValue * inputValue; in the while loop?

Comment: This is to maintain the loop invariant that `iValuesquared` must always be the square of `inputValue`. Without it, it sticks to an old value and causes the initial error. We want to compare 2 to 0.12*2*2, then 4 to 0.12*4*4, then 16 to 0.12*16*16. What happens if we don't do that is that 4 is compared to 0.12*2*2, 16 is compared to 0.12*2*2, etc, which is not the intention. The initial `long iValuesquared = inputValue * inputValue` sets iValuesquared to 4, but does not cause it to be recomputed when inputValue changes, which may be what is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while (inputValue > (0.12*iValuesquared)) {
```

You are looping **while** the input value is **bigger** than something.
The only value in that loop that increases is ... `inputValue`.

In other words: you want to loop ...while the value that you keep **increasing** is bigger than some other value.

Meaning: if this loop is entered, the condition will always evaluate to true. Because the **left** side of that comparison is increasing; but the right side is not!

And long story short: I think you are not getting your requirements clear. You take an input number, and square that; and expect to be different from the square of your input number?!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

You are running into a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). To fix that, you should use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Secondly you are assigning the newly squared value to the wrong variable inside the loop. From my point of view, it should be iValuesquared:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //define the variables
        BigInteger inputValue = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger iValuesquared = inputValue;

        do {
            System.out.println(iValuesquared + " is greater than 12% of it's squared value");
            iValuesquared = iValuesquared.pow(2);
        } while (new BigDecimal(iValuesquared.pow(2)).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.12)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(inputValue)) < 0);

        System.out.println(iValuesquared + " is less than 12% of it's squared value.");
    }
}
```

I changed the while loop to a do while, because then you do not need to have an initial check in front of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

*Ghislain Fourny* is right. His answer is the base for this one. The main difference is (besides the methods) that you can now set your threshold using `PRECENT` instead of changing it in multiple lines.

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    // Change this to alter the threshold
    public static final long PERCENT = 12;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long input = 2;
        long squared = square(input);

        while (input > threshold(squared)){
            System.out.println(input + " is greater than " + PERCENT + "% of it's squared value (" + squared + ")");
            input = squared;
            squared = square(input);
        }

        System.out.println(input + " is LESS than " + PERCENT + "% of it's squared value (" + squared + ")");
    }

    // Squares the given value and returns it
    public static long square(long value){
        return value * value;
    }

    // Calculates the threshold using the given value and the set percentage
    public static double threshold(long value){
        return (PERCENT / 100f) * value;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2 is greater than 12% of it's squared value (4)
4 is greater than 12% of it's squared value (16)
16 is LESS than 12% of it's squared value (256)
```